# What are the full names of the discoverers of the Seria oil field?

Tags: british-empire, natural-resources, brunei

History books and the [Brunei Shell Petroleum](https://www.bsp.com.bn/panagaclub/pnhs_old/geology/htm/oil&gas/fields/seria/seria1_2.htm) page say that the Seria oil field was jointly discovered by F.F. Marriot (British Malayan Petroleum Company) and by T.G. Cochrane (Sarawak Oilfields Limited).

What are these two men's full names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://bruneiresources.blogspot.com/2006/08/history-of-brunei-oil.html) is a blog post from 2006 that identifies Cochrane as

> Hon. Cochrane (later to become Lord Chochrane [sic] of Cults)

So [it appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Cochrane_of_Cults) his full name was "Thomas George Frederick Cochrane, 2nd Baron Cochrane of Cults"

Sorry nothing on Mr. Marriot so far...

**Edit:** Here is [another source](http://www.bruneiresources.com/goldenlegacy/tgl_oil_discovery.html), this one identifying TGC as "later Lord Cochrane"

Comment: I'm not convinced about [Thomas George Frederick Cochrane](http://thepeerage.com/p5286.htm#i52854) being the right man. First, He was a qualified barrister and served in the Black Watch during WW1 gaining the rank of Major. It would be strange for him to be in the oil business 10 years later and to only be referred to as "T.G. Cochrane" rather than "Major T.G.F. Cochrane" (which would be more accurate and appropriate).

Comment: @SteveBird I have added another source

Comment: @SteveBird According to your link, T.G. Cochrane was awarded with the companion D.S.O. after the war. There is an article about oil in Sarawak written by a certain Hon. T.G. Cochrane, D.S.O in the Journal of the Royal Society of Arts Vol. 72, No. 3723 (March 28, 1924), pp. 308-319 (link). This may be evidence that Thomas George Frederick Cochrane is the right man.